# Deduce Schema.DisplayType from a sample of JSON property values

Tags: apex, json, data-types, parser, sobjectfield

From a REST API my Apex is receiving a list of `JSON` objects with previously unknown properties. To store those properties I want to dynamically enhance a `Custom Object` by adding suitable Custom Fields using the Metadata API.

I currently struggle with deciding which `Schema.DisplayType` to use for each of the resulting target `SObjectField`s. As default I could just store everything in a text field, but I also would like to detect and match at least those further types:

A method `public Map<String, Schema.DisplayType> deduceType(String jsonArray)` should produce from

```
[{
    name : "Peter",
    age : 34,
    married: true,
    partner: "Lucy",
    diabetesRisk: 0.4
},
..
{
    name : "Martha",
    age : 88,
    married: false,
    partner: null,
    diabetesRisk: 1
}]
```

this output

```
{
    name --> DisplayType.String,
    age --> DisplayType.Integer,
    married --> DisplayType.Boolean,
    diabetesRisk --> DisplayType.Percent
}
```

**Ideas that came into my mind are:**

- Look at multiple value instances in the JSON (it's an array of same structure objects) to better cope with nulls or outlier values
- Test a [list of ordered Regexp pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775547/javascript-guess-data-type-from-string) (from Text to more specific)
- Maybe I can also use the `parse()` functions in Apex

Is there a better, a simpler or more robust approach? If so I would love to hear about it.

Comment: If the Json came in with all null property values, you'd be stuck.

Comment: `JSONParser`: `nextToken` or `nextValue` returns a `JSONToken` enum with type info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to parse the JSON and deduce its type using [JSONParser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_JsonParser.htm?search_text=Schema.DisplayType).

I couldn't find any direct mapping between [System.JSONToken](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_System_JsonToken.htm) and [Schema.displayType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_Schema_DisplayType.htm?search_text=Schema.DisplayType), So I have created a local map.

Since there is no JSON Token for `Date`, `DateTime`, and `Time` I have leveraged **JSONParser.getter** functions(An alternate approach would be to use regex for `URL` and `email` types)

From format perspective `Percentage`, `Currency` and `Number` are ambiguous, so I have kept it under Number category.

**Sample code:**

```
private Map<String, Schema.DisplayType> parse(String input) {
    Map<String, Schema.DisplayType> result = new Map<String, Schema.DisplayType>();
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(input);

    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {  
        if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            String name = parser.getCurrentName();
            parser.nextValue();
            result.put(name, type(parser));
        }
    }

    return result;
}


private Schema.DisplayType type(JSONParser parser) {
    Schema.DisplayType result;

    Map<System.JSONToken, Schema.DisplayType> displayType = new Map<System.JSONToken, Schema.DisplayType> {
        JSONToken.VALUE_FALSE => Schema.DisplayType.Boolean,
        JSONToken.VALUE_TRUE => Schema.DisplayType.Boolean,
        JSONToken.VALUE_NULL => Schema.DisplayType.String,
        JSONToken.VALUE_STRING => Schema.DisplayType.String,
        JSONToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT => Schema.DisplayType.Integer,
        JSONToken.VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT => Schema.DisplayType.Double
    };

    JSONToken type = parser.getCurrentToken();

    if(type == JSONToken.VALUE_STRING && isTime(parser)) {
        result = Schema.DisplayType.Time;
    }
    else if(type == JSONToken.VALUE_STRING && isDate(parser)) {
        result = Schema.DisplayType.Date;
    }
    else if(type == JSONToken.VALUE_STRING && isDateTime(parser)) {
        result = Schema.DisplayType.DateTime;
    }
    else {
        result = displayType.get(type);
    }

    return result;
}


private Boolean isDate(JSONParser parser) {
    try {
        parser.getDateValue();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


private Boolean isDateTime(JSONParser parser) {
    try {
        parser.getDatetimeValue();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


private Boolean isTime(JSONParser parser) {
    try {
        parser.getTimeValue();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


String input = '[ { "name": "Peter", "age": 34, "married": true, "partner": "Lucy", "diabetesRisk": 0.4, "testDate": "2020-05-21", "testDateTime": "2020-05-21T13:01:23", "testTime": "18:05" } ]';
System.debug(parse(input));
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "age": "INTEGER",
    "diabetesRisk": "DOUBLE",
    "married": "BOOLEAN",
    "name": "STRING",
    "partner": "STRING",
    "testDate": "DATE",
    "testDateTime": "DATETIME",
    "testTime": "TIME"
}
```

> It would not be a robust solution to rely on code to deduce datatypes
>   from sample JSON data. Admin should modify data types wherever necessary(Determining type for `Text, Text Area, and Rich Text` can be ugly and still not be 100% robust).

Comment: How do you cope with null value and with more specific types like dates percentages etc

Comment: For safer side, the parser function treats null as a text field. I have updated my solution to handle the data type. Deducing type for Percentage, Currency, RichText Area field is hard just from the format and it should be left for admins to modify if necessary

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write a full example, but I think it would be safe to go with a JSON.deserializeUntyped, then decode the keys to figure out what they should be. This gives you the types Boolean, Decimal, and Text, and from there, you need patterns (regular expressions) to detect date, date/time, picklist, and ID values. Considering that [json2apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) (not my app, obviously) is a thing, you're not the first to have done it, and it seems reasonable to do with fair accuracy.

Comment: What do you mean by decode? Try to cast?

Comment: @RobertSösemann I would envision the code would check `== null`, `instanceOf Boolean`, `instanceOf Decimal`, `instanceOf Id`, followed by casting to a String and regex checking for date and datetime values, otherwise assume a plain string. Repeat for all the entries, recursively if necessary.

Comment: Clearly this doesn't address things like distinguishing text lengths, text vs email addresses, URLs etc. plus numbers vs currency and numeric precision and significant figures etc. though that can be applied based on extra analysis. Of course such analysis would only be as good as the input data set.